# Integrate elasticbeanstalk with cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a webpage in Elastic beanstalk for entering username and password. I want to link that to the cognito user pool for verifiation

I have deployed code in elastic bean stalk and able to launch the webpage 
Created a user pool in cognito. In elastic bean stalk  iam getting the http address. But cognito requires https to be used as callback URL.

Answer (score 5):

For this to work, the load balancer needs to be able to accept https connections and an authentication rule needs to be added to the load balancer rule.

Follow these steps:

1. Provision [https on the Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)
2. Add a [Cognito Authentication Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) to your Load Balancer
3. In DNS, point the public domain name to the ELB address

Answer (score 1):

I'm usgin Amazon API Gateway for auth Cognito auth.
And All request proxy by API Gateway to Elastic beanstalk application server.

To connect API Gateway and Elastic beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk's load balancer should be **network load balancer**, not application load balancer.

change elb type to `--elb-type network` from `eb create`

And change to Elastic beanstalk to private for security

remove `--vpc.elbpublic` from `eb create`

You Don't want using API gateway and you want just add ssl to Elastic beanstalk this video would be helpful.

[Step 6: Deploying a Rails 5 app to Elastic Beanstalk - Configure custom domain and SSL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MSg2zmrVjw)

Comment: Do you recommend using AWS API Gateway or just SSL with Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Am I able to change those settings you did with terminal in Elastic Beanstalk Console?

Comment: Please, could you explain more how to configure it in this way?
I want to use Cognito -> API Gateway -> Beanstalk right now for testing I am using web console and configuration for this does not look so easy as you describe.